# Add new node with attribiutes to xml file

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I have a xml schema like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NEWS>
       <category title="title">
              <sbml title="title" value="SBML_NEWSBGCOLOR" version="7.26.23" />
              <sbml title="title" value="SBML_NEWSWIDTHTYPE" version="7.26.23" />
       </category>
</NEWS>
```

I'm using asp Classic and I have a form that passes 4 variables to create new `<sbml />` node.

```
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
objXML.async = False
objXML.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
strXMLFile = Server.MapPath("\") & "\admin\sbml\72623.xml"
if objXML.Load(strXMLFile) Then
       If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD")="POST" Then
              Set new_sbml = objXML.createElement("sbml")
              objXML.selectSingleNode(noInj(rq("M")) & "/category").appendChild(new_sbml)
              objXML.save strXMLFile
       End if
End if
```

By this method I just added new node but with no attributes, how can i set attributes for this node?

Comment: Post your solution as an answer to your question. Tag it, so that the next person can benefit from it.

Comment: I'd do that at first but couldn't do that since 24hrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found my answer

```
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
objXML.async = False
objXML.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
strXMLFile = Server.MapPath("\") & "\admin\sbml\72623.xml"
if objXML.Load(strXMLFile) Then
       If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD")="POST" Then
              Set new_sbml = objXML.createElement("sbml")
              new_sbml.setAttribute "title", new_title 'Here i set attribute
              objXML.selectSingleNode("/category").appendChild(new_sbml)
              objXML.save strXMLFile
       End if
End if
```